# M Query / Power Query if in / Expression.Error: We cannot apply an index of type List. Details

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to add a Custom Column using the following m query language:

`= if AccountType {{"I","E"}} then "IS" else "BS"`

Herewith is a screenshot of the Custom Column:

[image: Custom Column]

As you notice, no syntax errors are found, however, when I click OK, I get the following Error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot apply an index of type List. Details:
> Value=[Table]
> Index=[List]

I've looked at numerous websites, but couldn't find a solution to this. The closest match is [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Expression-Error-We-cannot-apply-indexing-to-the-type-Function/m-p/735371), but the answer is not very clear.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show some details of "I" and "E"?

Comment: The Column Value will either be "I" or "E" or "N", which is why I'm adding the Custom Column to distinguish when it's "I" or "E", then it's Income Statement, otherwise it's Balance Sheet... If you need more context, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `if List.Contains({"I","E"}, [AccountType]) then "IS" else "BS"`;

Or if the list is actually from a column, you can replace the {"I","E"} with a reference to the list's column, like in `if List.Contains(tablename[columnname], [AccountType]) then "IS" else "BS"`;

Or if the list is an actual list, you can replace the {"I","E"} with a reference to the actual list, like in `if List.Contains(listname) then "IS" else "BS"`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work

```
= if [AccountType] = "I" or [AccountType] = "E" then "IS" else "BS"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with a list or "in"? :)

Comment: The reason I ask is because of this - what happens when you have more fields you want to check - you don't want to write an endless list of "or"...

Comment: do you want to compare a column contents to some other list of matching items, then?  If so, thats just a left outer merge from another table

Comment: You could also use `if List.Contains({"I","E"}, [AccountType]) then "IE" else "BS"`; or if the list is actually from a column, you can replace the {"I","E"} with a reference to the list's column, like in `if List.Contains(tablename[columnname], [AccountType]) then "IE" else "BS"`; or if the list is an actual list, you can replace the {"I","E"} with a reference to the actual list, like in `if List.Contains(listname) then "IE" else "BS"`

Comment: Thank you @MarcPincince, please post this as an answer, because this is exactly what I was looking for!